# Bad Connection to FS

Tags: hadoop

I am using Cloudera Hadoop (cdh3u1) and I am stuck with the following error message:

```
[root@paul conf.class]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/training 
12/09/16 07:40:26 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:27 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 1 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:28 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 2 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:29 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 3 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 4 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:31 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 5 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 6 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 7 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 8 time(s).
12/09/16 07:40:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: peter/192.168.1.100:8020. Already tried 9 time(s).
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to peter/192.168.1.100:8020 failed on local exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

I ran this on the slave node called Paul and trying to connect to the master node called Peter. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace just says that the client running on paul is unable to connect to the Namenode running on 192.168.1.100 at port 8020 .

Check :

1) The namenode is running on peter/192.168.1.100:8020 . You can either do a jps in peter to check if the Namenode process is running , or try browsing 192.168.1.100:50070 from paul or localhost:50070 from peter in a browser to check if the web ui of namenode is coming up .

2) The "fs.default.name" in core-site.xml , which is "192.168.1.100:8020 " is the right address and port of the server where namenode is running .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got paul listed on the Node. Now I have two, peter and paul. (I used to have two slaves, paul and mary, but reduced it to one, just paul, coz I got tired switching the monitor cable from three computers). I couldn't browse 192.168.1.100:50070 from paul though, but that's okay. I had so many issues, like iptables, apache status. Thanks again for your help.